# Counting the number of rows returned from a search query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, pdo

I'm trying to set up an admin search feature that takes the values from the search fields, sends a query to the SQL database consisting of a table called 'data', and a table called 'tag', and returns both the results, and the number of rows. The results work perfectly fine, but the number of results don't. Here's the relevant code:

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM data";
    $where="";
    $params=array();
    if(!empty($idsearch)){
        $where.=" id = ? AND";
        $params[]=$idsearch;
    }
    if(!empty($approvedsearch)&&$approvedsearch!=="A"){
        $where.=" approved = ? AND";
        $params[]=$approvedsearch;
    }
    if(!empty($namesearch)){
        $where.=" name LIKE ? AND";
        $params[]=$namesearch."%";
    }
    if(!empty($emailsearch)){
        $where.=" email LIKE ? AND";
        $params[]=$emailsearch."%";
    }
    if(!empty($fileurlsearch)){
        $where.=" (url LIKE ? OR fileid LIKE ?) AND";
        $params[]="%".$fileurlsearch."%";
        $params[]="%".$fileurlsearch."%";
    }
    if(!empty($datesearch)){
        $where.=" timedate LIKE ? AND";
        $params[]=$datesearch."%";
    }
    if(!empty($tagsearch)){
        $query.=" INNER JOIN tags ON tag.data_id = data.id";
        $tags=explode(" ",$tagsearch);
        $tagMarks=substr(implode(array_pad(array(),count($tags),"?, ")),0,-2);
        $where.=" tag.name IN (".$tagMarks.") AND";
        $params=array_merge($params,$tags);
    }
    if($where !== ""){
        $where=substr($where,0,-4);
        $query.=" WHERE ".$where/*." LIMIT ".$lowlim.", ".$uplim*/;
    }
    $countQuery="SELECT count(DISTINCT data.id) as count FROM data ".$where;
    $countQuery.=" INNER JOIN tags ON tag.data_id = data.id";
    $countQuery.=" WHERE ".$where;
    $countQuery.=" GROUP BY data.id";
    $countQuery=$con->prepare($countQuery);
    $countQuery->execute($params);
    $rowResult=$countQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $totalRows=$rowResult[0]['count'];
    $query.=" GROUP BY data.id";
    $query=$con->prepare($query);
    $query->execute($params);
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $datas=array();
    foreach($results as $result){
        $result['tag']=array();
        $datas[$result['id']]=$result;
    }
    $dataIds=array_keys($datas);
    $dataMarks=substr(implode(array_pad(array(),count($dataIds),"?, ")),0,-2);
    $query=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tag WHERE data_id IN (".$dataMarks.")");
    $query->execute($dataIds);
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($results as $result){
        $dataId=$result['data_id'];
        $datas[$dataId]["tag"][]=$result;
    }
    foreach($datas as $data){
        $tags=array();
        foreach($data['tag'] as $tag){
            $tags[]=$tag['tag_name'];
        }
?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$data['id']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['approved']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['name']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['email']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['fileid']?><?=$data['url']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['notes']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['timedate']?></td>
    <td><?=implode(", ",$tags)?></td>
</tr>    
<?php }?>
```

The countQuery is the problematic issue, I think, but the error getting thrown up is `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/admin.php on line 97`, which is `$totalRows=$rowResult[0]['count'];`

Comment: This is because your query returns nothing. Did you check for mysql errors?

Comment: also you can make this `$totalRows` calculation fail safe: `$totalRows = (isset($rowResult[0]) && isset($rowResult[0]['count'])) ? $rowResult[0]['count'] : 0;`

Comment: @TobiasKun: How do I do that? And what sort of errors could it be, if they are displaying the table's results correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found your mysql syntax error:

You are adding the `$where` part twice to your query and you seem to have a little spelling mistake here `tags ON tag.data_id`:

```
$countQuery="SELECT count(DISTINCT data.id) as count FROM data ".$where;
$countQuery.=" INNER JOIN tags ON tag.data_id = data.id";
$countQuery.=" WHERE ".$where;
$countQuery.=" GROUP BY data.id";
```

Try to fix it:

```
$countQuery="SELECT count(DISTINCT data.id) as count FROM data ";
$countQuery.=" INNER JOIN tags ON tags.data_id = data.id";
$countQuery.=" WHERE ".$where;
$countQuery.=" GROUP BY data.id";
```

**EDIT**

Please set the error handling in PDO as following:

`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

With this setting an exception will be thrown. I've also found a spelling mistake. See above (`tags` and `tag.data_id`)

**EDIT 2**

You received the following exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY
>   data.id' at line 1' in /var/www/admin.php:96 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/admin.php(96): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown
>   in /var/www/admin.php on line 96

So the `GROUP BY` is not valid, which makes sense, since you only count. Remove it:

```
$countQuery="SELECT count(DISTINCT data.id) as count FROM data ";
$countQuery.=" INNER JOIN tags ON tags.data_id = data.id";
$countQuery.=" WHERE ".$where;
```

Comment: Bit of a silly mistake on my end. Fixed that, but `echo $totalRows` still gives me 0, based on that suggestion to alter the $totalRows line in the question's comments.

Comment: @user3331834 I've updated my answer. Please try this and tell me if any exception is thrown.

Comment: Fixed the mistake. Still nothing. Error thrown by your edit: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY data.id' at line 1' in /var/www/admin.php:96 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/admin.php(96): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/admin.php on line 96

Comment: The exception should say everything :D I've updated my answer.

Comment: You mean just remove the GROUP BY line? I assume so, since those three lines you edited in are what I still have. I've commented it out, and now it gives the same message, except instead of "...use near 'GROUP BY...", I simply get "...use near '' at line 1"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Yc0R8u2n This should be everything on the page that is in some way related to the search query

Comment: This won't help much :( What i need to know is this: What does the `$where` contain? What is the full count sql query, that is finally inserted into PDO?

Comment: the $where will contain different things, depending on what search terms have been submitted. Since there are multiple inputs, a check is first run to see if they have any values. If they don't, they are ignored. Any input that does have a value will then have a where clause added to it, which specifies what the SQL column value should be when the query is run. I was told that if I want to count the number of returned rows, the query I run to count the rows must be almost exactly the same as the query used to search for data.

Comment: Yes, but I need the STRING. The query that is finally send to the database. How could i find syntax errors if i do NOT know the full query. I did realize that the query is build from different parts, but i do need the final STRING value to look for malformatting etc

Comment: Search query:"SELECT * FROM data INNER JOIN tag ON tag.data_id = data.id WHERE  id = ? AND approved = ? AND email LIKE ? AND (url LIKE ? OR fileid LIKE ?) AND timedate LIKE ? AND GROUP BY data.id". Row query: "SELECT count(DISTINCT data.id) as count FROM data  INNER JOIN tag ON tag.data_id = data.id WHERE  id = ? AND approved = ? AND email LIKE ? AND (url LIKE ? OR fileid LIKE ?) AND timedate LIKE ? AND  GROUP BY data.id". Perhaps the issue lies with that leftover AND?

Comment: @user3331834 why don't you learn SQL **prior** trying to use it in PHP?

Comment: Is it me, or is everyone with a 5 digit reputation here an arrogant prick? What do you think I'm trying to do in the meantime, genius?

Comment: @user3331834: Calm down! Look at your Row query. The last `AND` in your `WHERE` clause is to much.